# Using Google Annotated Time Line Chart Without Flash

Tags: google-visualization

I want a similar behavior Chart as Google Annotated Time Line Chart to display my Time Series Data from DataBase In our environment we are restricted using Flash .

But i see that Google Annotated Time Line Chart works only with Flash .

I want a similar behavior as of Google Annotated Time Line Chart showing two charts , where the below Chart helps us to select a Range and the Upper Chart displays the Zoomed Area .

I wanted to develop this by taking two divs , but i am struck up as how to maintain synchronization between these two divs (Chart Div and Slider Div)

If anybody developed has developed Google Annotated Time Line Chart Without Flash , please give some inputs as how to develop this .

Thank you very much for reading .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

It's not free but it looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

check out https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#chartrangefilter_control

I believe you can do simple annotations also using data roles 'annotation' and 'annotationtext' (not too much styling though). You can find more info here https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles.

Answer (score 0):

there is no other way to make charts in Google without Flash at the moment